# To be approached vs. To being approached

Tags: grammar, expressions, to-infinitive

I have read this sentence:

> How do I find out if a woman is receptive
> *to being approached by me?*

Omitting "being",

Can I say:

> How do I find out if a woman is receptive *to be approached by me?*

or totally omitting it:

> How do I find out if a woman is receptive *to approached by me?*

What is the difference between these sentences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "be receptive to (something)" ends in the preposition *to* and must be followed by a noun phrase. The *to* that appears here is different from the word *to* that appears in the infinitive of a verb (as in "to know").

"Being approached by me" is a noun phrase. The word "being" is a verbal noun. This *-ing* form refers abstractly to the action denoted by the verb.

For example, one can say "Living in Oklahoma is a lot of fun." Here "living in Oklahoma" is a noun phrase that refers to the state of being a resident of Oklahoma. The example of "being approached" is slightly more complicated because "to be approached" is in the passive voice, but the principle is the same.

Neither of the two suggestions you made is possible. In "receptive to," the word *to* can only be followed by the *-ing* form of a verb.